# Merging two paged resultsets

Tags: .net, linq, asp.net-membership

Since asp.net Membership does not allow to search simultaneously by username and email, I think i should merge results from those two paged resultsets.

Has anybody done this before?
Or this is unimplementable idea?

FYI signatures of "merged" methods:

```
MembershipUserCollection FindUsersByName( string usernameToMatch,
                                                                int pageIndex, 
                                                                int pageSize, 
                                                                out int totalRecords )

MembershipUserCollection FindUsersByEmail( string  emailToMatch,
                                                                 int     pageIndex, 
                                                                 int     pageSize, 
                                                                 out int totalRecords )
```

The result method signature should be like:

```
MembershipUserCollection MergedUsersAndEmailsSearch( string  userOrEmailToMatch,
                                                             int     pageIndex, 
                                                             int     pageSize, 
                                                             out int totalRecords )
{
//here we calling FindUsersByName and FindUsersByEmail and merging them
}
```

Comment: @sarwar026 has a answer that would work, but you could also `UNION` the results in the LINQ query to avoid double DB calls.

Answer (score 0):

Does it work?

```
collection1 = FindUsersByName(...);
collection2 = FindUsersByEmail(...);

collection1.ToList().AddRange(collection2.ToList());
```

Comment: No, it does not look to pageIndex. I should write it in question